# django save() method saving the manytomany field why do we need save_m2m()

Tags: python, django

I have refered this documentation page for save() method
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

But in my view I have the following code

```
def saveEvent(request):
eventForm = EventForm(request.POST)
if eventForm.is_valid():
    event=eventForm.save(commit=False)
    requestor=None
    if(event.is_hp_requestor):
        #Save and get requestor
        requestorHPPersonForm = PersonHiddenForm(request.POST, prefix = 'hp_requestor')
        requestorHPEmployeeForm = HPEmployeeForm(request.POST, prefix = 'hp_requestor')
        requestor=saveHPEmployeeHelper(requestorHPEmployeeForm, requestorHPPersonForm).person
    else:
        requestorHPPersonForm = PersonHiddenForm(request.POST, prefix = 'hp_requestor')
        requestor=get_object_or_404(Person, pk=requestorHPPersonForm.data[requestorHPPersonForm.prefix+'-'+'email'])

    if (requestor is not None) and eventForm.is_valid():
        event.requestor_new=requestor
        event.save()
        if request.POST['opportunities']:
            for str_sfid in request.POST['opportunities'].split(','):
                sfid = int(str_sfid)
                opportunity_object, dummy = Opportunity.objects.get_or_create(sfdc_id=sfid)
                event.opportunities.add(opportunity_object)
        event.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
else:
    errors = eventForm.errors
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(errors), status=500, mimetype='application/json')
```

In my view I do not invoke the save_m2m() method, but still it save many2many field data.
How is it works, if this is working then why we need the save_m2m() method?

Comment: I don't think you need later event.save() line.

Comment: The second `save` is unnecessary, yes. `add` saves the many-to-many relationship when you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you linked to explain this:

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False). When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls.

Also, it looks like `event` is itself a model instance rather than a form. `save_m2m` is required for forms, not model instances.

To paraphrase the explanation in the docs: a form's `save` method, if called with `commit=True` (the default) does two things - it creates a new model instance using the form's cleaned data, and it writes that model instance to the database. Then, if there are any many-to-many relationships, it writes those to the database as well. It does that after writing the instance because you can't write a many-to-many relationship until the instance has a primary key, which is auto-generated when you write it to the database.

If you call the form's `save` method with `commit=False`, it creates the new model instance but it does not write it to the database. Thus, it has no primary key yet and the many-to-many information can't be saved either. After you save the model instance and therefore generate a primary key for it, the many-to-many information is still stored only in the form object. So you need to notify the form object that it's now OK to save the many-to-many information, by calling `save_m2m`.

*edit* Since you've added more of your code I can see more clearly what you're asking. The above code will not save many-to-many relationships that are set in your `EventForm` instance. Is that what your loop to set opportunities is doing?

Comment: Peter, Sorry I just updated the full view code, Please refer the same

Comment: opportunities is the m2m field. I have checked in backend that m2m details are getting saved with this code.

Comment: Yes, your above code parses out opportunities from the POST directly - it's redundant to have both that and a field on the form. Assuming the form field works as you expect, anyway - many-to-many fields do not generally work by splitting a single text block on commas, although you could write a custom widget that does so. `save_m2m` is required to save many-to-many information from the form after using `commit=False`, and your view code creates that information using a different approach and ignores anything in the form.